# upload video to you tube directly from wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using you tube uploader to upload vedios directly from wordpress. But its saying invalid authentication. can anybody suggest any ways to directly upload video from wordpress to you tube.

Comment: more info please, are you talking about this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-uploader/ ?

Comment: actually i want to upload a video directly from wordpress without going out of the site any plugins other than you tube uploader which is not working

Comment: yes i am talking about wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-uploader

Comment: its a plugin but it seems to be not working

Comment: @user2008654, welcome to StackOverflow, you may want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The documentation has interesting things: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget

Answer (score 2):

## YouTube Uploader

> This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be
>   maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used
>   with more recent versions of WordPress.

[YouTube Uploader](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-uploader/)

Maybe thats the reason.

Comment: yes any other plugin or a way to upload videos directly from worpress